# HA configuration for KVM Guest on iSCSI shared storage

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, high-availability, iscsi, netapp

My requirement is to provide HA to a Zimbra Server. We want Zimbra files to be installed in a Netapp SAN which is providing around 5.7 TB as a SAN iSCI Drive. Since Netapp comes in with Dual Controller and stable performance, we are unlikely to have any down time.

I have 2 servers each having Xeon processor 6 Core, 32 GB RAM and 2 x 250 GB SSD. These are the two servers where I have installed CentOS 7.6. We would like to have one as primary and the second one as secondary.

Idea is to use the same principle of KVM HA ( What Redhat and even VMware) provides, so that if the primary goes down the IP gets switched to secondary, to create a simple Hot Redudant system.

We have a very few users on Zimbra, but there are a lot of automated emails coming in and we require a very large storage, and hence we are using the Netapp box.

I am able to switch between the KVMs. However I am struggling to figure out how I need to mount the iSCI target, so that the mail application stays alive.

Zimbra typically installs on /opt/. Do I mount the target on /opt/, and if so will it work? Or am I missing something else?

Or should I run the VM of the shared storage itself, and if so how can I configure it.

Zimbra itself is a combination of a database and files, and uses a number of services to keep itself active. Idea of using a shared storage is for Redundancy and high availability.

I have tried to configure HA but i was stuck over STONITH fence_agents.

By the way i followed this Documentation-

https://www.lisenet.com/2016/activeactive-high-availability-pacemaker-cluster-with-gfs2-and-iscsi-shared-storage-on-centos-7/

Appreciate your response and support.

Comment: I have tried to configure but i was stuck over stonith fance-agent configuration.

Comment: active/active setups are much more difficult to maintain than active/passive. Are you sure that you can not support a 1 minute downtime, especially in the context of emails delivery (smtp protocol is natively dealing with retries in emails delivery). A much simpler setup would be to allocate a netapp lun and install the kvm machine on it, and using something like opensvc, dealing with kvm high availability between nodes.

Comment: I don't think he is looking at a Active-Active, It's an Active-Passive from what I understand

Comment: Yes i don't need active-active i want active passive setup.